# Key Error despite using the correct column name

Tags: python, pandas

The column's name is 'description'. The error is pointing at the regular expressions line, where I am trying to replace any non-letter characters from the description column with spaces.

Thanks for the help!

```
df = pd.read_csv('winemag-data_first150k.csv')
dataset = df[['description', 'points']]
train = dataset.sample(frac = 0.1, random_state = 200)
test = dataset.drop(train.index)
train.head()
wordlist = []
for elem in range(1,15093):
    taste = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', train["description"][elem])
    taste = taste.lower()
    taste = taste.split()
    PorStem = PorterStemmer()
    judge = [PorStem.stem(word) for word in taste if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]    
    judge = ' '.join(judge)
    wordlist.append(judge)
```

The error -

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-4a7dc36c2440> in <module>()
  1 wordlist = []
  2 for elem in range(1,15093):
----> 3     taste = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', train["description"][elem])
  4     taste = taste.lower()
  5     taste = taste.split()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
600         try:
--> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
602 
603             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
2475         try:
2476             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2477                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 
 'tz', None))
2478         except KeyError as e1:
2479             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()  

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1
```

Comment: do you need `train.loc[elem, "description"]` instead `train["description"][elem]` ?

Comment: Please add a transcript of the error your receive, along with the traceback. But I believe you need `loc` ^.

Comment: That gives me `KeyError: 'the label [1] is not in the [index]'` instead

Comment: I updated the post with the error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
#select column description
description = dataset.sample(frac = 0.1, random_state = 200)['description']
#use pandas str text function
description = description.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ').str.lower().str.split()
PorStem = PorterStemmer()
#apply function
f = lambda x: ' '.join([PorStem.stem(word) for word in x if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))])
#convert output to lists
wordlist = description.apply(f).values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! If you don't mind me asking, where can I better learn to implement features like that? I'm weak with concepts such as lambda and its applications.

Comment: @Abcd - Really hard question, maybe the best are pandas tutorials from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html)